# Calling Rscript from linux shell script

Tags: r, linux, bash, shell, rscript

Can anyone suggest how I might get this working....

I have an R script that takes several minutes to run and writes a few hundred lines of output. I want to write a shell script wrapper around this R script which will launch the R script in the background, pipe its output to a file and start following the bottom of that file. If the user then enters CTRL-C I want that to kill the shell script and tail command but not the R script. Sounds simple right?

I've produced a simplified example below, but I don't understand why this doesn't work. Whenever I kill the shell script the R script is also killed despite apparently running in the background. I've tried nohup, disown etc with no success.

example.R

```
for(i in 1:1000){
   Sys.sleep(1)
   print(i)
}
```

wrapper.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

Rscript example.R > logfile &

tail -f logfile
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, that's not it. If I do that I get two jobs running in the background and CNTL-C doen't kill either of them. I want CNTL-C to kill tail -f but not Rscript.

Comment: I don't have access to `R`, but I just tried this exact script with PHP and it works as described. Ctrl-C kills the parent script but leaves the background process running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following seems to work on my Ubuntu machine:

```
#!/bin/bash

setsid Rscript example.R > logfile.txt &

tail -f logfile.txt
```

---

Here are some of the relevant processes before sending `SIGINT` to `wrapper.sh`:

```
 5361 pts/10   00:00:00 bash
 6994 ?        00:00:02 update-notifier
 8519 pts/4    00:00:00 wrapper.sh
 8520 ?        00:00:00 R
 8521 pts/4    00:00:00 tail
```

and after `Ctrl+C`, you can see that `R` is still running, but `wrapper.sh` and `tail` have been killed:

```
 5361 pts/10   00:00:00 bash
 6994 ?        00:00:02 update-notifier
 8520 ?        00:00:00 R
```

---

Although appending your `Rscript [...]` command with `&` will send it to the background, it is still part of the same process *group*, and therefore receives `SIGINT` as well.

---

I'm not sure if it was your intention, but since you are calling `tail -f`, if not interrupted with `Ctrl+c`, your shell that is running `wrapper.sh` will continue to hang even after the R process completes. If you want to avoid this, the following should work,

```
#!/bin/bash

setsid Rscript example.R > logfile.txt &

tail --pid="$!" -f logfile.txt
```

where `"$!"` is the process id of the last background process executed (the `Rscript [...]` call).

Comment: Thanks for this answer which does exactly what I was looking for.